# lvconvert number of mirrors

Tags: hard-drive, lvm, mirroring

I have a logical volume that is mirrored, it has two copies of the data and also its log is mirrored. It was created using something like:

```
lvcreate -m 1 --mirrorlog
```

I am planning to move this data to 2 new disks. The  end result should be the same as its original state but in new disks. I was planning on using lvconvert, breaking the initial mirror converting to a linear volume, creating a new one with two copies (-m 2) on the new disks and removing the old one. The last step is the one I am concern about, how should the lvconvert syntax be to eliminate the last old volume?

```
lvconvert -m 1 --mirrolog <old_volume>???
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do that in two steps,

```
lvconvert -m0 vgname/lvname /dev/device_to_remove_of_old_one
```

Now you converted your mirror to linear and it reside on one old disk, Now you can copy your data to the new one disk

```
lvconvert -m 1 --mirrolog mirrored vgname/lvname /dev/one_of_your_new_device
```

Now your mirror has one side in your old disk and other on new one, We can now remove the old one

```
lvconvent -m0 vgname/lvname /dev/the_old_last_one
```

Now you can do the last step

```
lvconvert -m 1 --mirrolog mirrored vgname/lvname /dev/second_of_your_new_device
```

Now your mirror is on your new disks, I think you can reduce the number of steps, using pvmove, But I had many problems with that command in the pas.